# In Node/Express, can I connect to an external data API stream with a websocket, and then pass that stream between my server and client files?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io, ws

My app currently connects to the same data stream API twice, once from server.js and once from client.js.  This seems inefficient.

> example:  wss://stream.example.com:5555/ws/GMT4@weatherdata (pushes data)

Is it possible to pass an externally-sourced data stream between server.js and client.js?

- with internal websockets, with socket.io or ws
- with internal REST API routes
- by some other method

Thank you.

Edit:
I've added one solution in the comments.
Is there any room for improvement?  Thanks again.

Comment: Well, in some cases, the client can just connect directly to the target stream without involving your server.  Otherwise, the data will have to flow through your server one way or the other and then it's not really clear what you're asking for help with since you show no code and don't ask a very specific question about your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:  thanks to some help from socket.io, this method works:

[Github repo](https://github.com/respectabiggle/socket.io-project)

dependencies

```
socket.io
socket.io-client
ws
express
```

index.html

```
<body>
    <script src="../socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
</body>
```

client.js

```
const socket = io();

socket.on('channel1', (foo) => {
    console.log(foo);                                            
});
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app); 
server.listen(3000, () => console.log("Express Running on PORT 3000")); 
app.use(express.static('public'));

const { Server } = require('socket.io'); 
const io = new Server(server);      

const { WebSocket } = require('ws');
const client = new WebSocket('wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@trade');

client.on('message', (event) => {
    let parse = JSON.parse(event); 
    let data = parseFloat(parse.p)
    // console.log(data)          
    io.emit('channel1', data);   
});
```